# pH Dependency of IR Stretching Frequency in CO-binded Heme Protein

Tags: biochemistry, ph, ir-spectroscopy

If one consumes CO, then CO binds with Heme Protein forming a Fe-CO bond. My question is if there will be any **pH dependency on IR Stretching Frequency, i.e. ν(CO) and ν(Fe-CO)**. And if there is, then what will be the result?